# css animation filter:blur(0) элемент пропадает

Tags: css, анимация

Создана простенькая карусель на `css`, на нижние изображения по
умолчанию установлено свойство `filter:blur(3px)`, когда элемент становится на первый план, `blur` устанавливается в `"0"`, при этом элемент пропадает на мгновение и сразу появляется. Как исправить этот баг?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f34;
}

.slider_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #6ce555;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider_container div {
  margin: auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide_img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.first_el {
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  filter: blur(3px);
  transition: filter 2s linear;
  background: #f55cad;
  transform: translateX(25%);
  animation: bottom-from-l-to-r 5s linear infinite;
}

.second_el {
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: #f50cad;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: from-r-to-l 5s linear infinite;
}

.third_el {
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
  background: #f57cad;
  /*   filter:blur(3px); */
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  animation: from-l-to-r 5s linear infinite;
}


/* animation for first element */

@keyframes bottom-from-l-to-r {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(175%);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.2);
    z-index: 2;
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  99% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    z-index: 0;
  }
}


/*  animation for second element*/

@keyframes from-r-to-l {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) scale(1.2);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
    z-index: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(75%);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) scale(1.2);
    z-index: 2;
  }
}


/*  animation for third element*/

@keyframes from-l-to-r {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-100%) scale(1.2);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-175%);
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
  <div class="first_el">
    <img src="http://revelstokeartscouncil.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Bear.jpg" alt="" class="slide_img" />
  </div>
  <div class="second_el">
    <img src="http://static.metacritic.com/images/products/movies/7/9c446be45735ae7dcfb3ff1a3a78ebac.jpg" alt="" class="slide_img" />
  </div>
  <div class="third_el">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51o33fuVLpL.jpg" alt="" class="slide_img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[просмотреть визуализацию и код можно по ссылке](https://codepen.io/EvgenR/projects/public/) [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/EvgenR/projects/public/).

Comment: чего-то не видно этой проблемы...

Comment: в хроме открой я не прописывал префиксы

Comment: У меня опера. это одно и тоже

Comment: и что блур работает нормально?

Comment: У меня блюриться только медведь... Но ничего не пропадает

Comment: да только медведь. блин ладно дома проверю мож на работе хроме не обновлён

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76731/discussion-between-evgeniy-r-and-air).

Answer (score 0):

*Предположительно проблема в аппаратном ускорении браузера CHROME. В Огненной Лисе blure(Xpx) отрабатывает нормально. В Chrom - через раз, в зависимости от загрузки процессора*